# accesing contacts via omnicontacts gem routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gmail, contacts, omniauth

hey i'm trying to access contacts from gmail/yahoo etc using omnicontacts gem,
https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts

i'm able to get the responce from the site but not able to rout to my page and getting routing errors

Internal Server Error

uninitialized constant ContactsLists
and
uninitialized constant ContactsListsController
or
The action 'gmail' could not be found for InvitesController

config files are below

```
Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "client_id", "client_secret", {:redirect_path => "/contact_callback"}

end
```

in google console

Redirect URIs   is set to
mylocaldomain.com/contact_callback

and i want t oroute the data to my contact_list controller and invite method so in routes i have defined

```
 match "contact_callback" => '/contacts_lists/invitenew'
```

and i'm getting http://mylocaldomain.com/contact_callback?code=4/jGYoPAYuZiuW5uR2UjDPmqF6Hjtj.4oxoCiD-BVUQXE-sT2ZLcbShVA5nhwI

let me know what i'm doing wrong.

** EDIT **

omnicontacts.rb

```
#check https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts for more info

Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "XXX", "****", {:redirect_path => "/contact_lists/gmail/contact_callback"}

  importer :yahoo, "XXX", "****", {:callback_path => "/conta"215641561956751", "86245e1a6e7ce9b9e59cf440d5262e12",ct_lists/yahoo/contact_callback"} 

  importer :hotmail, "000000004011440B", "ah89ykZYvM1CcohvJhdcfEKaJL9Oktjt" , {:redirect_path => "/contact_lists/hotmail/contact_callback"}

  importer :facebook, "XXX", "****", {:redirect_path => "/contact_lists/facebook/contact_callback"}
end
```

routes.rb

```
  get "/contact_lists/facebook/contact_callback" => "contact_lists#getfbinvite"
 # get "/contact_lists/:provider/contact_callback" => "contact_lists#getinvite" #commented temp
  get "/contact_lists/gmail/contact_callback" => "contact_lists#getinvite"
   get "/contact_lists/yahoo/contact_callback" => "contact_lists#getinvite"
    get "/contact_lists/hotmail/contact_callback" => "contact_lists#getinvite"
```

This will solve the problem for me.now i have all diff function for all sites as per requirement. Hope this helps you .

Comment: hi, were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, i got it working finnaly!!

Comment: Same problem here. Could you share your solution with us?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan check the edits. Sorry for late replay.